# Smooth color animation

Tags: android

I'm trying to create smooth color animation in my WaveView. Unfortunatelly animation is creating rainbow effect spamming through every color from start to end.

I'll need it to go from Red to Green with just (Red -> Orange - > Yellow - > Greenish -> Green) like on RGB tables.

Here's my ObjectAnimator:

```
ObjectAnimator waveColor = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(
            mWaveView, "waveColor",Color.parseColor("#64ff0000"),Color.parseColor("#6400ff00"));

    waveColor.setDuration(7000);
    waveColor.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animators.add(waveColor);
```

I have no idea how to make it to just go through that colors.

Comment: write your own custom `android.animation.TypeEvaluator<T>`

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Transition):

Hope I have understood your question properly and it helps

```
    ColorDrawable[] color = {new ColorDrawable(Color.RED), new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN)};
    TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(color);
    //This will work also on old devices. The latest API says you have to use setBackground instead.
    mWaveView.setBackgroundDrawable(trans);
    trans.startTransition(7000);
```

Comment: I dont want to change color of background, but waves. The issue is that WaveView accept only ints as colors.

Comment: have you used any third party for WaveView or you are creating your own?

Answer (score 0):

best way use ValueAnimator and ColorUtils.blendARGB

```
 ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, 1.0f);
 valueAnimator.setDuration(325);
 valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

              float fractionAnim = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

              view.setColorBackground(ColorUtils.blendARGB(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")
                                    , Color.parseColor("#000000")
                                    , fractionAnim));
        }
});
valueAnimator.start();
```